# How to overlay figures and merge shapes and put text in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to alter this graph https://texample.net/tikz/examples/arrow-table/ in a way that "inbound" and "logistics" goes over all 4 upper lines - while also making it possible to write in the thereof created four fields on the upper panel. For Operations I want that it only overlays the lines currently with "technology and development" as wells as "Procurement".

I also would love to combine the "marketing & sales" and "services area" and overlay it with the two lines above.

To achieve my goal I have several questions:

1. How can I overlay fields in tikz? I found this page, https://tikz.dev/tikz-transparency
2. How can I make the text of the upper parts being in the newly created smaller areas?
3. How can I combine fields in the lower part of the error.

I know this isn't a minimal example, however, I really hope for some help with my 3 questions.

For convenience, here is the code from the texasmple

```
% Table in the shape of an arrow
% Author: Gonzalo Medina
```

````
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\definecolor{colone}{RGB}{209,220,204}
\definecolor{coltwo}{RGB}{204,222,210}
\definecolor{colthree}{RGB}{207,233,232}
\definecolor{colfour}{RGB}{248,243,214}
\definecolor{colfive}{RGB}{245,238,197}
\definecolor{colsix}{RGB}{243,235,179}
\definecolor{colseven}{RGB}{241,231,163}

\tikzset{ 
  table/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={rectangle,text width=2cm,align=center},
    text depth=1.25ex,
    text height=2.5ex,
    nodes in empty cells
  }
}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\cbox}[1]{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (mat) [table] {
    |[fill=colfour]|      & |[fill=colfour]|  & |[fill=colfour]|
      & |[fill=colfour]|  & |[fill=colfour]|  &                   \\
    |[fill=colfive]|      & |[fill=colfive]|  & |[fill=colfive]|
      & |[fill=colfive]|  & |[fill=colfive]|  &                   \\
    |[fill=colsix]|       & |[fill=colsix]|   & |[fill=colsix]|
      & |[fill=colsix]|   & |[fill=colsix]|   & |[fill=colsix]|   \\
    |[fill=colseven]|     & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]|
      & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & |[fill=colone]|   \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & |[fill=colone]|   \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   &                   \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   &                   \\
  };

  % horizontal rules
  \foreach \row in {2,3,4}
    \draw[white] (mat-\row-1.north west) -- (mat-\row-6.north east);
  \draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-1-6.north east);
  \draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-5-1.north west) -- (mat-5-6.north east);

  % vertical rules
  \foreach \col in {2,3,4,5}
    \draw[white] (mat-5-\col.north west) -- (mat-8-\col.south west);

  % The labels
  \node[fill=colfour] at (mat-1-3) {Firm Infrastructure};
  \node[fill=colfive] at (mat-2-3) {Human Resources Management};
  \node[fill=colsix] at (mat-3-3) {Technology Development};
  \node[fill=colseven] at (mat-4-3) {Procurement};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-1) {\cbox{Inbound Logistics}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-2) {\cbox{Operations \\\mbox{}}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-3) {\cbox{Outbound Logistics}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-4) {\cbox{Marketing \& Sales}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-5) {\cbox{Service \\\mbox{}}};
  \node[rotate = 90] at ([xshift=-52pt]mat-3-1.north)
    {\textsc{Support Activities}};
  \node at ([yshift=-19pt, xshift=-0.5cm]mat-8-3.south)
    {\textsc{Primary Activities}};

  % Erase some visible lines outside the arrow
  \fill[white] (mat-1-5.north east) -- (mat-5-6.north east)
    -- (mat-1-6.north east) -- cycle;
  \fill[white] (mat-8-5.north east) -- (mat-5-6.north east)
    -- (mat-8-6.north east) -- cycle;

  % Draw the arrow tip
  \shade[top color=colfour!70, bottom color=colfour!70,
    middle color=colseven, draw=white, ultra thick] 
    (mat-1-5.north) -- (mat-5-6.north) -- (mat-8-5.south) -- 
    (mat-8-5.south east) -- (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-8-5.south east) -- 
    (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-1-5.north east) -- cycle;

  % The slanted "Margin" labels
  \begin{scope}[decoration={markings,
    mark=at position .5 with \node[transform shape] {Margin};}]
  \path[postaction={decorate}] 
    ( $ (mat-1-5.north)!0.5!(mat-1-5.north east) $ )
    -- ( $ (mat-5-6.north)!0.5!(mat-5-6.north east) $ );
  \path[postaction={decorate}] 
    ( $ (mat-5-6.north)!0.5!(mat-5-6.north east) $ )
    -- ( $ (mat-8-5.south)!0.5!(mat-8-5.south east) $ );
  \end{scope}

  % The braces
  \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, raise=6pt}]
    (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-5-1.north west);
  \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, raise=6pt}]
    (mat-8-1.south west) -- (mat-8-5.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 2):

You should take a moment to understand how the diagram is built, then it should not be too complicated to achieve what you want.

First, the whole thing is based upon a matrix. This matrix consists of six columns and eight rows.

When being stripped off the colored boxes and nodes, it looks like the following picture (I kept the tip and the braces, however):

[image]

Now, the single cells of this matrix are simply filled with specific colors and white lines are added at the borders of some of the cells. This way, it looks as if different cells are connected, but they really are not. There is just no border between some of the cells.

Finally, nodes that contain text are positioned in such a way that the text sits approximately in the center of the colored shaped generated by the above approach. Thus, the text labels are completely unrelated to the shapes they appear to sit in.

To sum up, it is neither necessary to merge shapes nor to overlay "fields" to achieve what you want. You simply need to change the color of some of the cells, redraw some of the lines and maybe reposition some of the nodes that contain the text. You can also add more nodes to add more text if you wish.

I am not quite sure whether this is in any way similar to what you want to achieve, but at least it can serve as a starting point, I guess:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\definecolor{colone}{RGB}{209,220,204}
\definecolor{coltwo}{RGB}{204,222,210}
\definecolor{colthree}{RGB}{207,233,232}
\definecolor{colfour}{RGB}{248,243,214}
\definecolor{colfive}{RGB}{245,238,197}
\definecolor{colsix}{RGB}{243,235,179}
\definecolor{colseven}{RGB}{241,231,163}

\tikzset{ 
  table/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={rectangle,text width=2cm,align=center},
    text depth=1.25ex,
    text height=2.5ex,
    nodes in empty cells
  }
}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\cbox}[1]{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (mat) [table] {
    |[fill=colone]|      & |[fill=colfour]|  & |[fill=colfour]|
      & |[fill=colfour]|  & |[fill=colfour]|  &                   \\
    |[fill=colone]|      & |[fill=colfive]|  & |[fill=colfive]|
      & |[fill=colfive]|  & |[fill=colfive]|  &                   \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colsix]|
      & |[fill=colsix]|   & |[fill=colsix]|   & |[fill=colsix]|   \\
    |[fill=colone]|     & |[fill=coltwo]| & |[fill=colseven]|
      & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & |[fill=colone]|   \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & |[fill=colone]|   \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   &                   \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   &                   \\
  };

  % horizontal rules
  \foreach \row in {2,3}
    \draw[white] (mat-\row-2.north west) -- (mat-\row-6.north east);
  
  \draw[white] (mat-4-3.north west) -- (mat-4-6.north east);
  \draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-3-2.north west) -- (mat-3-2.north east);
  \draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-5-3.north west) -- (mat-5-6.north east);

  % vertical rules
  \foreach \col in {4,5}
    \draw[white] (mat-5-\col.north west) -- (mat-8-\col.south west);

  \draw[white] (mat-1-2.north west) -- (mat-8-2.south west);
  \draw[white] (mat-3-3.north west) -- (mat-8-3.south west);

  % The labels
  \node at (mat-1-3) {Firm Infrastructure};
  \node at (mat-2-3) {Human Resources Management};
  \node at (mat-3-4) {Technology Development};
  \node at (mat-4-4) {Procurement};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-1) {\cbox{Inbound Logistics}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-2) {\cbox{Operations \\\mbox{}}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-3) {\cbox{Outbound Logistics}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-4) {\cbox{Marketing \& Sales}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-5) {\cbox{Service \\\mbox{}}};
  \node[rotate = 90] at ([xshift=-52pt]mat-3-1.north)
    {\textsc{Support Activities}};
  \node at ([yshift=-19pt, xshift=-0.5cm]mat-8-3.south)
    {\textsc{Primary Activities}};

  % Erase some visible lines outside the arrow
  \fill[white] (mat-1-5.north east) -- (mat-5-6.north east)
    -- (mat-1-6.north east) -- cycle;
  \fill[white] (mat-8-5.north east) -- (mat-5-6.north east)
    -- (mat-8-6.north east) -- cycle;

  % Draw the arrow tip
  \shade[top color=colfour!70, bottom color=colfour!70,
    middle color=colseven, draw=white, ultra thick] 
    (mat-1-5.north) -- (mat-5-6.north) -- (mat-8-5.south) -- 
    (mat-8-5.south east) -- (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-8-5.south east) -- 
    (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-1-5.north east) -- cycle;

  % The slanted "Margin" labels
  \begin{scope}[decoration={markings,
    mark=at position .5 with \node[transform shape] {Margin};}]
  \path[postaction={decorate}] 
    ( $ (mat-1-5.north)!0.5!(mat-1-5.north east) $ )
    -- ( $ (mat-5-6.north)!0.5!(mat-5-6.north east) $ );
  \path[postaction={decorate}] 
    ( $ (mat-5-6.north)!0.5!(mat-5-6.north east) $ )
    -- ( $ (mat-8-5.south)!0.5!(mat-8-5.south east) $ );
  \end{scope}

  % The braces
  \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, raise=6pt}]
    (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-5-1.north west);
  \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, raise=6pt}]
    (mat-8-1.south west) -- (mat-8-5.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or maybe, you are after something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\definecolor{colone}{RGB}{209,220,204}
\definecolor{coltwo}{RGB}{204,222,210}
\definecolor{colthree}{RGB}{207,233,232}
\definecolor{colfour}{RGB}{248,243,214}
\definecolor{colfive}{RGB}{245,238,197}
\definecolor{colsix}{RGB}{243,235,179}
\definecolor{colseven}{RGB}{241,231,163}

\tikzset{ 
  table/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={rectangle,text width=2cm,align=center},
    text depth=1.25ex,
    text height=2.5ex,
    nodes in empty cells
  }
}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\cbox}[1]{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (mat) [table] {
    |[fill=colone]|      & |[fill=colfour]|  & |[fill=colfour]|
      & |[fill=colfour]|  & |[fill=colfour]|  &                   \\
    |[fill=colone]|      & |[fill=colfive]|  & |[fill=colfive]|
      & |[fill=colfive]|  & |[fill=colfive]|  &                   \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colsix]|
      & |[fill=colsix]|   & |[fill=colsix]|   & |[fill=colsix]|   \\
    |[fill=colone]|     & |[fill=coltwo]| & |[fill=colseven]|
      & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & |[fill=colone]|   \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & |[fill=colone]|   \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   &                   \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   &                   \\
  };

  % horizontal rules
  \foreach \row in {2,3,4}
    \draw[white] (mat-\row-1.north west) -- (mat-\row-6.north east);

  \draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-5-1.north west) -- (mat-5-6.north east);

  % vertical rules
  \foreach \col in {4,5}
    \draw[white] (mat-5-\col.north west) -- (mat-8-\col.south west);

  \draw[white] (mat-1-2.north west) -- (mat-8-2.south west);
  \draw[white] (mat-3-3.north west) -- (mat-8-3.south west);

  % The labels
  \node at (mat-1-3) {Firm Infrastructure};
  \node at (mat-2-3) {Human Resources Management};
  \node at (mat-3-4) {Technology Development};
  \node at (mat-4-4) {Procurement};

  \node at (mat-1-1) {One};
  \node at (mat-2-1) {Two};
  \node at (mat-3-1) {Three};
  \node at (mat-4-1) {Four};
  
  \node at (mat-3-2) {Five};
  \node at (mat-4-2) {Six};

  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-1) {\cbox{Inbound Logistics}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-2) {\cbox{Operations \\\mbox{}}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-3) {\cbox{Outbound Logistics}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-4) {\cbox{Marketing \& Sales}};
  \node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-5) {\cbox{Service \\\mbox{}}};
  \node[rotate = 90] at ([xshift=-52pt]mat-3-1.north)
    {\textsc{Support Activities}};
  \node at ([yshift=-19pt, xshift=-0.5cm]mat-8-3.south)
    {\textsc{Primary Activities}};

  % Erase some visible lines outside the arrow
  \fill[white] (mat-1-5.north east) -- (mat-5-6.north east)
    -- (mat-1-6.north east) -- cycle;
  \fill[white] (mat-8-5.north east) -- (mat-5-6.north east)
    -- (mat-8-6.north east) -- cycle;

  % Draw the arrow tip
  \shade[top color=colfour!70, bottom color=colfour!70,
    middle color=colseven, draw=white, ultra thick] 
    (mat-1-5.north) -- (mat-5-6.north) -- (mat-8-5.south) -- 
    (mat-8-5.south east) -- (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-8-5.south east) -- 
    (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-1-5.north east) -- cycle;

  % The slanted "Margin" labels
  \begin{scope}[decoration={markings,
    mark=at position .5 with \node[transform shape] {Margin};}]
  \path[postaction={decorate}] 
    ( $ (mat-1-5.north)!0.5!(mat-1-5.north east) $ )
    -- ( $ (mat-5-6.north)!0.5!(mat-5-6.north east) $ );
  \path[postaction={decorate}] 
    ( $ (mat-5-6.north)!0.5!(mat-5-6.north east) $ )
    -- ( $ (mat-8-5.south)!0.5!(mat-8-5.south east) $ );
  \end{scope}

  % The braces
  \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, raise=6pt}]
    (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-5-1.north west);
  \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, raise=6pt}]
    (mat-8-1.south west) -- (mat-8-5.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is already super helpful because yeah, I did not get the matrix environment at all. I just need to figure out how to overlay instead of connect (e.g., the inbound logistics going over all the upper four areas while they are still recognizable as distinct full lines).

Comment: As I would like to put some text in the "overlaid" areas, too.

Comment: @canIchangethis If you need concrete help, I can try to edit the answer and add some more information.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would need to keep the four white horizontal lines from far left to far right, however through "overlay" it would look colourwise differently and I would be able to write text in the fields that are currently invisible over "inbound logistics" - is that possible.